# 6 sec audio delay when screen recording on iPad

Tags: ipad, audio, screen-capture

When I do a screen recording on my iPad Pro generation 2, the sound that goes with the video is reliably delayed 6 seconds.  This means that there's 6 seconds of silence, and that the last 6 seconds of sound that should have been recorded are cut off from the video.  I believe that this problem used to either not happen or to be much less pronounced, but I can't think of anything that I might have changed to cause this delay.  What might I try to diagnose the cause of, and fix, the error?

EDIT:  It's been getting longer over time.  For a while I started getting 7s delays, and now the delay is up to 10s or more.  It stays mostly constant on groups of takes, but has been creeping up over time.  (I'm recording lots of screencasts for an online class.)

Comment: What version of iOS do you have installed?

Comment: @Nic, iOS 13.3.1.